# Model/View theory

Tags: python, qt, model

(I'm using Python/Qt, but this could be for any language...)

I have a model which is a container object and supports functions such as `__len__(...)` and `__getitem__(...)`, etc.  I'm actually implementing a custom ring buffer using numpy, but that's besides the point.  It also has an `append(...)` function.

I also have a view which is a UI element (derives from `QWidget`).  It has buttons, an instance of a `QTableView`, and it also has an `append(...)` function which, based on the state of the UI, conditionally forwards the data to the underlying model.  It also has a `model()` function which returns the model from the `QTableView` instance, ie it just does `return myTableViewInstance.model()`

**My question** is whether the View should also contain functions such as `__len__()` and `__getitem__(...)` which are forwarded to the model directly, so the user of the view only ever interacts with the view, or whether it's legitimate for the user to get the model via `model()`, and do stuff directly to the model, such as `len(myView.model())` or `myView.model()[1:100]`

On the one hand it seems redundant to just forward stuff along from View down to Model, but it also seems like it's cheating/dirty to get the model and manipulate it directly, since that violates the spirit of model/view.

Comment: The user of the view shouldn't need the model at all; the view should be creating all of the GUI components it needs to.

Comment: Take a look at one of Qt's own convenience view classes (such as [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html)). They usually provide *both* ways to interact with the model. But they don't attempt wrap *all* of the model's functionality. Only the most commonly required things have a higher-level API, and the rest is accessible via the model itself.